# Define logic in settings bundle (iOS)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, settings, bundle

Is it possible to define in the plist the following: "If Item 1 is enabled, then enable Item 2 otherwise keep it disabled"? This seems like a simple thing that a lot of setting may require, but I can't find a way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing, are you talking about creating the info.plist dynamically (while compiling) or are you talking about manipulating it afterwards (when invoking the app)?

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible. The settings bundle is a static thing and third-party developers cannot add dynamic behavior to it.